# How to parse out a html-element without a class, id etc

Tags: c#, visual-studio, html-agility-pack

I have a problem with C# and the HtmlAgilityPack. 
I would like to parse out the price of a material but I don't know exactly how to access this item. It's a "td-element" in a "tr". The problem is that there are 3 "td-elements" and I can't manage to access the 2nd one but only the first one. I hope you understand my problem and could help me.

This is the HTML-Code that I want to access:

```html
<tr role="row" class="odd" id="itemTable" data-name="clay_r" data-server="1">
    <td>Lehm</td>
    <td>$191</td>
    <td><input class="itemboxes" data-name="clay_r" data-server="1" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>

<tr role="row" class="odd" id="itemTable" data-name="coal_r" data-server="1">
    <td>Kohle</td>
    <td>$303</td>
    <td><input class="itemboxes" data-name="coal_r" data-server="1" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
```

This is the code I`ve wrote down in C#, and it is working, but just for the first td-element each:

```cs
var products = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("id", "")
                .Equals("accordion1")).ToList();

var productListItems = products[0].Descendants("tr")
    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("data-name", "")
    .Contains("")).ToList();


foreach (var productListItem in productListItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(productListItem.GetAttributeValue("data-name", ""));
    Console.WriteLine(productListItem.Descendants("td").FirstOrDefault().InnerText);

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

When I start the program, that is displayed in the Console:

clay_r
Lehm

coal_r
Kohle

Just as I want it, but instead of "Lehm" or "Kohle" the price of the items should be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault()` return first `td` (means `<td>Lehm</td>`)

Use this :

```
var tds = productListItem.Descendants("td").ToList();

var name = tds[0].InnerText;
var price = tds[1].InnerText;

Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Attention of `IndexOutOfRange` exception

Comment: `Descendants` returns IEnumerable, you can't use index accessor. Either enumerate first with `ToArray`/`ToList` or use `Skip(1)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I have a problem. I know, I should know that, but since I'm very new to C#, I still can't make it:  
http://prntscr.com/orm6zg  
Where exactly should I load your code into my project?

Comment: But still I've got another question. Now all variables are displayed correctly (http://prntscr.com/ormdxx). First row "data-name", second row "name", third row "price". Now I would like to assign each price to a variable (string), which I can access later... So like: "string LehmPreis  = <price of the first item(name = Lehm, data-name = clay_r)>".
I hope you can help me with that :)

Comment: @DavidB hit : Convert.ToInt32(your_string)

Comment: Yes, but I need to get the "price" into an string.. How can I do this with your code? I just want to create a string for every material (so around 30 strings) and then get the price of every particular material in these strings. It's because I need this values for a calculator, that gets the numbers from a server. And now I want to get these values and calculate a value that depends on the users selection of material.

Comment: When I try this (http://prntscr.com/ormv5j) there are all material names saved into that string. But I only want one (for the nameString string I only Want "Lehm", not all material-names). Also I have a problem with the convertion, when I try int.Parse(price) I get an FormatException Error.

Comment: I get the FormatException also when I try "Convert.ToInt32(price)".

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution to Antoine V's which is *really clean*  :
I'd name the tds with an attribute "price" and add a clause in your where pointing to the "price".

And access it by this way:

Replace this

```
Console.WriteLine(productListItem.GetAttributeValue("data-name", ""));
```

By this

```
Console.WriteLine(productListItem.Attributes['price'].value));
```

Otherwise, add a class to each td (such as "name" "price" and "chkbox" for example)

```
Console.WriteLine(productListItem.Descendants("td").Attributes["price"].value);
```

Hope it helps ?

Comment: See edit David ? Just added you another alternative